# Uncaught TypeError with Modernizr.Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, modernizr

I'm trying to get the following code to work allowing me to use the datepicker. Whilst I have had a variation of this working previously I'm now unable to get it working after a restore.

I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' below the line 'Modernizr.load'

```
    <script>
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
  nope: ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js', 'jquery-ui.css'],
    complete: function () {
        if (window.jQuery) {
            jQuery('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Any suggestions as to what the cause of this error is?

Comment: This might help others.  Searching Uncaught TypeError for `Modernizr.mq` landed me here.  I didn't realize `mq()` media queries were not always in the script so updating to the latest version of Moderinzr fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I just pasted a simple modernizr custom build in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/25/) which seems to work for firefox:

However, I had to change the way you load jquery-ui: simply replace that cdn with your desired theme:

```
    nope: [
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js', 
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css'],
    ....
```

Mins was right, here the custom build:

[image]

Comment: Note: Modernizr's custom builder has had a revamp since this answer. I'm not sure if this is even still possible. But maybe someone can shine a light on this

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` means that you are trying to call something as a function that does not exist. In this case, you are calling several functions by reference.

`Modernizr.load`, and `jQuery().datepicker`. That means that either `Modernizr.load` doesn't exist, in which case make sure that the [Modernizr.load checkbox is checked](http://cl.ly/image/1u2q0B2O1F3S). If it is datepicker that is causing the issue, then you need to check your developer tools network log to see if

1. jQuery UI is downloading
2. it is being parsed correctly (no errors are being thrown in the console for it).

Also, jQuery 1.4 is 4 and a half years old! Try and use a newer version if you can, there are a ton of speed improvements in later versions!

Comment: I've made sure I have the latest Modernizr and jQuery 1.9.1 and everything seems to be loading OK. The error has changed slightly with the console now saying:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 1027:29
Modernizr.load.complete 1027:29
c modernizr-2.8.1.js:845
h modernizr-2.8.1.js:845
B modernizr-2.8.1.js:845
Modernizr.load modernizr-2.8.1.js:846
(anonymous function)
HOw do I make sense of that? Is it something to do with Modernizr not being able to process the datepicker test?

Answer (score 0):

The *development* version of *Modernizr.js* doesn't include `load()`. To get this function you need to use the [library builder](http://modernizr.com/download/) and check *load* option in the *Extra* section.

[image]

The reason given by the *Modernizr* team:

> We don't include it because it's actually a separately maintained
>   library called yepnope - you can get it at
>   https://github.com/slexaxton/yepnope.js

More here:
[Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'load' #307](https://github.com/modernizr/modernizr/issues/307)